# boost.property_tree read json expected end of input

Tags: c++, json, boost

I'm using boost to read a JSON file
this is my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    try
    {
        boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
        boost::property_tree::read_json("macAddr.txt", pt);

        BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type& v, pt)
        {
            BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type& i, v.second)
            {
                std::string s = i.second.get_value("");
                std::cerr << s << "\n";
            }
            std::cerr << "\n\n";
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

and it throws exception "macAddr.txt(1): expected end of input"

the content of the JSON file is:

```
[{"mac":"60:21:C0:20:6A:8C","power":-73,"sensor_id":254,"timestamp":"2015-05-16 19:32:19"},{"mac":"CC:FA:00:B4:3D:44","power":-52,"sensor_id":254,"timestamp":"2015-05-16 19:32:17"},{"mac":"CC:3A:61:82:D1:20","power":-76,"sensor_id":254,"timestamp":"2015-05-16 19:32:12"},{"mac":"0C:48:85:FF:1C:2D","power":-79,"sensor_id":254,"timestamp":"2015-05-16 19:32:12"},{"mac":"34:A3:95:A2:00:2E","power":-76,"sensor_id":254,"timestamp":"2015-05-16 19:32:11"}]
```

Comment: needs a reproducer (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In principle this doesn't make sense unless the has changed or you're not reading the same file the second time

Comment: im writng the data to macAddr.json and then reading as json evrey second

Comment: My comment wasn't intended as a start of a debate. I said what I said. It's a fact. Except, of course if you want to include [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in the picture. Did I mention you need to eliminate errors and make a SSCCE/MVCE?

Comment: Hilariously, the code didn't change. However, you changed the problem description removing the things that blatantly didn't make sense. Now, we just need to know the contents of the JSON file. Because, likely it contains trailing data...

Comment: The added sample doesn't exhibit the error with the code suplied, see my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have trailing data, like e.g.

```
{ "a" : 1 }
{ "b" : 2 }
```

Property tree will only read the first toplevel object or array.

**Update**

The MVCE is not an issue:  **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f576ba638e9d39e4)**

With a trailing word, you'll see the error you report: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c072802cd2037b00)**

Comment: i didnt understand what causes the trailing word

Comment: You cause it. Or a program that writes the json. In [my sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c072802cd2037b00) I just added the word "trailing": `[{"mac":"60:21:C0:20:6A:8C","power":-73,"sensor_id":254,"timestamp":"2015-05-16 19:32:19"}] trailing`

Comment: Thank you, found the problem!

Comment: Don't keep us in suspense!

Comment: As you said i had trailing data, i didnt delete the old data before writing to the file

Comment: Cheers. Thanks for the update. Welcome to [SO]. Don't forget to tell us when things helped http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work